# PurifyCSS with Bootstrap | Nav-Tab not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, uncss

I've build a simple Bootstrap 3 page and wanted to increase the load speed using PurifyCSS.
Everything works fine (even the carousel), however the Nav-Tabs are not working.

I have included links to the Purified and Raw CSS

RAW Bootstrap CSS:
http://pastebin.com/bTVtKRZc

After Purify (unminified)
http://pastebin.com/SBEC42c5

I checked both files and .nav-tabs or the .nav base class can be found in both files,however the tabs only work when I load the unpurified version.

The html code of the tabs :

http://pastebin.com/Gu70PdHR

I am new to CSS and Web Design in general and would appreciate any help or hints.

I have also included a uncss tag, as I encountered the same problem under uncss (after adding the classes to ignore)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font `@import` from your purified is missing quotes.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700);
```

to

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700");
```

Also it might be stripping used classes, you would have to manually check.